# Cannot Select name of object via variable ID, using param, templates and for each cycle

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am pretty sure I am doing this right, but my paths are messed up somewhere.

What I am trying to do is create a table that contains the information of all configurations in the XML that have an i5 or i7 processor, taking the component IDs from the configurations element and matching them up with the component names from the components element. I've only attempted to do this for two elements - Config_Name and MB_Producer. Config_Name is successfully displayed but I fail to acquire the names of the motherboards. Please help!

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PCStore>
<Components>
    <Motherboards>
        <MB_Producer id="1">ASRock</MB_Producer>
        <MB_Producer id="2">GIGABYTE</MB_Producer>
        <MB_Producer id="3">Foxconn</MB_Producer>
        <MB_Producer id="4">Asus</MB_Producer>
        <MB_Producer id="5">MSI</MB_Producer>
    </Motherboards>
    <HDDs>
        <HDD_Producer id="1">WD</HDD_Producer>
        <HDD_Producer id="2">Seagate</HDD_Producer>
        <HDD_Producer id="3">Baracuda</HDD_Producer>
        <HDD_Producer id="4">TOSHIBA</HDD_Producer>
        <HDD_Producer id="5">LG</HDD_Producer>
    </HDDs>
    <Physical_Memory>
        <RAM_Producer id="1">Kingston</RAM_Producer>
        <RAM_Producer id="2">Corsair</RAM_Producer>
        <RAM_Producer id="3">Transcend</RAM_Producer>
        <RAM_Producer id="4">SanDisk</RAM_Producer>
        <RAM_Producer id="5">Maxell</RAM_Producer>
    </Physical_Memory>
    <CPUs>
        <CPU_Producer id="1">Intel i3</CPU_Producer>
        <CPU_Producer id="2">Intel i5</CPU_Producer>
        <CPU_Producer id="3">Intel i7</CPU_Producer>
        <CPU_Producer id="4">AMD Athlon</CPU_Producer>
        <CPU_Producer id="5">AMD Phenom</CPU_Producer>
    </CPUs>
    <GPUs>
        <GPU_Producer id="1">NVIDIA</GPU_Producer>
        <GPU_Producer id="2">AMD</GPU_Producer>
        <GPU_Producer id="3">Intel</GPU_Producer>
        <GPU_Producer id="4">GIGABYTE</GPU_Producer>
        <GPU_Producer id="5">Sapphire</GPU_Producer>
        <GPU_Producer id="6">Palit</GPU_Producer>
    </GPUs>
    <Cases>
        <Case_Producer id="1">SPIRE</Case_Producer>
        <Case_Producer id="2">SWEEX</Case_Producer>
        <Case_Producer id="3">CoolerMaster</Case_Producer>
        <Case_Producer id="4">Antec</Case_Producer>
        <Case_Producer id="5">AOpen</Case_Producer>
        <Case_Producer id="6">Corsair</Case_Producer>
    </Cases>
</Components>
<Configurations>
    <Configuration>
        <Config_Name>Base Model</Config_Name>
        <MB_Producer>3</MB_Producer>
        <Case_Producer>1</Case_Producer>
        <Hard_Drive>
            <HDD_Producer>1</HDD_Producer>
            <Size>360GB</Size>
        </Hard_Drive>
        <Physical_Memory>
            <RAM_Producer>3</RAM_Producer>
            <Size>2GB</Size>
        </Physical_Memory>
        <Processor>
            <CPU_Producer>1</CPU_Producer>
            <Clock_Rate>2.6Ghz</Clock_Rate>
        </Processor>
        <Video_Card>
            <GPU_Producer>3</GPU_Producer>
            <Memory>256MB</Memory>
        </Video_Card>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
        <Config_Name>Gaming Entry Model</Config_Name>
        <MB_Producer>2</MB_Producer>
        <Case_Producer>4</Case_Producer>
        <Hard_Drive>
            <HDD_Producer>2</HDD_Producer>
            <Size>360GB</Size>
        </Hard_Drive>
        <Physical_Memory>
            <RAM_Producer>3</RAM_Producer>
            <Size>4GB</Size>
        </Physical_Memory>
        <Processor>
            <CPU_Producer>2</CPU_Producer>
            <Clock_Rate>3.2Ghz</Clock_Rate>
        </Processor>
        <Video_Card>
            <GPU_Producer>2</GPU_Producer>
            <Memory>512MB</Memory>
        </Video_Card>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
        <Config_Name>Mid-Level Gaming Model</Config_Name>
        <MB_Producer>5</MB_Producer>
        <Case_Producer>2</Case_Producer>
        <Hard_Drive>
            <HDD_Producer>4</HDD_Producer>
            <Size>500GB</Size>
        </Hard_Drive>
        <Physical_Memory>
            <RAM_Producer>5</RAM_Producer>
            <Size>8GB</Size>
        </Physical_Memory>
        <Processor>
            <CPU_Producer>3</CPU_Producer>
            <Clock_Rate>3.6Ghz</Clock_Rate>
        </Processor>
        <Video_Card>
            <GPU_Producer>1</GPU_Producer>
            <Memory>1024MB</Memory>
        </Video_Card>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
        <Config_Name>Pro-Gamer Model</Config_Name>
        <MB_Producer>2</MB_Producer>
        <Case_Producer>3</Case_Producer>
        <Hard_Drive>
            <HDD_Producer>2</HDD_Producer>
            <Size>1024GB</Size>
        </Hard_Drive>
        <Physical_Memory>
            <RAM_Producer>1</RAM_Producer>
            <Size>16GB</Size>
        </Physical_Memory>
        <Processor>
            <CPU_Producer>3</CPU_Producer>
            <Clock_Rate>3.8Ghz</Clock_Rate>
        </Processor>
        <Video_Card>
            <GPU_Producer>1</GPU_Producer>
            <Memory>1024MB</Memory>
        </Video_Card>
    </Configuration>
</Configurations>
</PCStore>
```

And here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="PCStore">
<html>
<head>
<title>Configurations</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Задача 2, Данаил Найденов, F66840</h2>
<h3>Configurations</h3>
<table border="6">
<tr bgcolor="#AFAFAF">
  <td>Configurations</td>
  <td>MB_Producer</td>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="Configurations/Configuration">
 <xsl:sort select="Config_Name"/>
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Config_Name"/></td>
                <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="PCStore/Components/Motherboards">
                        <xsl:with-param name="MB_Producer" select="MB_Producer" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PCStore/Components/Motherboards">
    <xsl:param name="MB_Producer" />
    <xsl:value-of select="MB_Producer[@id=$MB_Producer]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd really appreciate any help...

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is that you are in the context of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Configurations/Configuration">
```

when you try to apply templates to:

```
PCStore/Components/Motherboards
```

This is a *relative* path, and the current context node (Configuration) has no PCStore child. You need an *absolute* path, starting from the root, in the form of:

```
 /PCStore/Components/Motherboards
```

Note that you do not need to repeat the entire path when defining the template's match pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="Motherboards">
```

will work just fine.

---

**ADDENDUM**:

Not directly related to your question, but I think you could simplify this by doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="components" select="/PCStore/Components" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Configurations</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Задача 2, Данаил Найденов, F66840</h2>
<h3>Configurations</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Configurations</th>
      <th>MB_Producer</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="PCStore/Configurations/Configuration">
    <xsl:sort select="Config_Name"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Config_Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$components/Motherboards/MB_Producer[@id=current()/MB_Producer]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using a **key** is another way to get "related" data, the most preferred one in terms of performance - so it just might be worth the effort of setting up a dedicated key for each component type.